# SSH + Rails: Run Rails (and Capistrano) commands with ssh session in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, ssh, capistrano

I want to know if there's a way to do like

```
ssh user@host "cap production rails:console"
```

where `host` is my Rails development environment, and then be able to use the remote console.

When I try that command, it shows: `bash: cap: command not found`

Then I tried to run

```
ssh user@host "bundle exec cap production rails:console"
```

but it shows `bash: bundle: command not found`

Note that I use `rvm`.

My `.bashrc` (excerpts):

```
....
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

...

#linuxbrew
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable 
change. export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

# for transcriber service
export SOUNDNOTATION_TRANSCRIBER_BINARY_PATH="$HOME/transcriber/SoundnotationTranscriber"
# sidekiq
export TRANSCRIPTION_API_HOST_PORT='localhost:4040'

# wkhtmltopdf
export WKHTMLTOPDF="/home/soundnotation/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf"

eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use full path to cap:

```
ssh user@host "/Users/anton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@gotoweb/bin/cap production rails:console"
```

?

Comment: When I log in, the default path is the app path, so yes. Even adding the app path manually though, the result is the same

Comment: Try to use absolute path for cap. Updated my answer.

Comment: The error now is: `/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby_executable_hooks’: No such file or directory`

Comment: It looks like it also related to PATH. As I get, ssh doesn't properly load your path variables. I saw some solutions on generating binstubs. Try it `rvm @global do gem regenerate_binstubs; gem regenerate_binstubs`.